# Is it possible to pass Python Future objects between processes?

Tags: python, concurrent.futures

Based on my experiments I'm guessing the answer to this is no. But perhaps it might be possible with some changes to the futures module.

I would like to submit a worker that itself creates an executor and submits work. I want to return that second future to the main process. I have this MWE, which does not work because the `f2` object likely becomes disassociated from its parent executor when it is sent over via multiprocessing. (It does work if both executors are ThreadPoolExecutor, because the `f2` object is never copied).

```
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor, ThreadPoolExecutor
import time

def job1():
    try:
        ex2 = ThreadPoolExecutor()
        time.sleep(2)
        f2 = ex2.submit(job2)
    finally:
        ex2.shutdown(wait=False)
    return f2

def job2():
    time.sleep(2)
    return 'done'

try:
    ex1 = ProcessPoolExecutor()
    f1 = ex1.submit(job1)
finally:
    ex1.shutdown(wait=False)

print('f1 = {!r}'.format(f1))
f2 = f1.result()
print('f1 = {!r}'.format(f1))
print('f2 = {!r}'.format(f2))
```

My question is: Is there any safe way that I might send a future object across a multiprocessing Pipe and be able to receive the value when it is finished. It seems like I might need to set up another executor-like construct that listens for results over another Pipe.

Comment: I'm not super familiar with the Python's `concurrent` library, but I've been looking into Ray recently. From what I understand of your question (which, admittedly isn't very great, and is one of the reasons I'm not submitting an answer), Ray very might well be able to solve your problem if you're willing to look outside of the standard library. You can read about it here: https://rise.cs.berkeley.edu/projects/ray/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My current setup is Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS and Python 3.6.5. I received the following error when running the code posted above:

```
f2 = f1.result()
```

followed by

```
concurrent.futures.process.BrokenProcessPool: A process in the process pool was terminated abruptly while the future was running or pending.
```

Looking through the Python documentation, I found under 17.4.3. ProcessPoolExecutor that

> "calling Executor or Future methods from a callable submitted to a ProcessPoolExecutor will result in deadlock."

Further, under

```
class concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=None)
```

I also found the following:

> "changed in version 3.3: when one of the worker processes terminates abruptly, a BrokenProcessPool error is now raised. Previously, behaviour was undefined but operations on the executor or its futures would often freeze or deadlock."

Further, by definition the ProcessPoolExecutor turns off the Global Interpreter Lock, opening it to access by other processes.

To answer your question on whether any safe way is available to send a future object across a multiprocessing pipe and receive it on the other end, I would say no with the standard library.

References:

https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/concurrent.futures.html#processpoolexecutor

https://docs.python.org/3.6/glossary.html#term-global-interpreter-lock